# What is the two parametric solution of the equation $\ x^2−cy−d=0 $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm looking for a two parametric solution of a Diophantine equation of this kind: $\ x^2−cy−d=0 $, in the set of natural numbers.

Comment: Note there are values of $c$ and $d$ for which there are no integer solutions eg $x^2=3y+2, x^2=8y+6$. Where $c$ and $d$ have no prime factor in common you need that $d$ is a quadratic residue modulo $c$.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a solution of the following type?

Let $d$ be a q.r. modulo $c$. (Otherwise there is no solution, as pointed out by Mark Bennet.)

Then there is a solution $x_0^2=cy_0+d$.

Then the general solution is 
$$x=\pm x_0+tc,y=y_0\pm2tx_0+t^2c.$$